# Apply code for all else first block

Tags: widgets

I have this code for sidebar in Wordpress :-

```
 register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Main sidebar',
'description' => 'main sidebar.',
'before_widget' => '<div id="blocks" class="siderbar box_outer %2$s" style="visibility: hidden;"><div class="widget">',
'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget_title">',
'after_title' => '</h3><div class="wid_border"></div>'
  ));
```

In this cod will add every widget attribute `style="visibility: hidden;"`, but i need to add this attribute for all widget else first widget.

How can do that by php or JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you want to do would better be done with CSS rules in your stylesheet rather than with an embedded `style` tag that you dynamically manipulate with PHP.

Remove `style="visibility: hidden;"` from your `register_sidebar` argument and use something like the following instead (Proof of Concept):

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .aclass { visibility:hidden }
    .aclass:first-child { visibility:visible }
  </style>
</head>
<body><?php
  for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="aclass">'.$i.'</div>';
  } ?>
<body>
</html>
```

That is purely to make the two necessary rules apparent. You can run that code to get a feel for things if you'd like. You will need to swap `aclass` for the class you need to target-- either `siderbar` or `box_outer` I presume. And you probably want to write the rules into your main stylesheet.